# Return file from python module

Tags: python, file, mime-types, download

Edit: How to return/serve a file from a python controller (back end) over a web server, with the file_name? as suggested by @JV

Comment: The question is incomplete I guess.
Did u mean return/serve a file from a python controller (back end) over a web server, with proper mime-type set and name?

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with Python.  This is a question on the HTTP Return type.  How you set the return type depends on your web server.  What web server framework are you using?

Comment: @S.lott - I am using cherrypy. how do i send the filename with the cherrypy response?

Comment: Please update the question with all facts, include a snippet of code that you are currently using that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully supported in CherryPy using

```
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file
```

As documented in the [CherryPy docs - FileDownload](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/FileDownload):

```
import glob
import os.path

import cherrypy
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file


class Root:
    def index(self, directory="."):
        html = """<html><body><h2>Here are the files in the selected directory:</h2>
        <a href="index?directory=%s">Up</a><br />
        """ % os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(directory))

        for filename in glob.glob(directory + '/*'):
            absPath = os.path.abspath(filename)
            if os.path.isdir(absPath):
                html += '<a href="/index?directory=' + absPath + '">' + os.path.basename(filename) + "</a> <br />"
            else:
                html += '<a href="/download/?filepath=' + absPath + '">' + os.path.basename(filename) + "</a> <br />"

        html += """</body></html>"""
        return html
    index.exposed = True

class Download:
        def index(self, filepath):
        return serve_file(filepath, "application/x-download", "attachment")
        index.exposed = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.download = Download()
    cherrypy.quickstart(root)
```

Comment: The indentation of the class `Download` is off. The return isn't under the `index` method and the use of 8 spaces is inconsistent with the 4 spaces used elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can either pass back a reference to the file itself i.e. the full path to the file. Then you can open the file or otherwise manipulate it.

Or, the more normal case is to pass back the file handle, and, use the standard read/write operations on the file handle.

It is not recommended to pass the actual data as files can be arbiterally large and the program could run out of memory.

In your case, you probably want to return a tuple containing the open file handle, the file name and any other meta data you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

For information on MIME types (which are how downloads happen), start here: [Properly Configure Server MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Properly_Configuring_Server_MIME_Types).

For information on CherryPy, look at the attributes of a [Response](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ResponseObject) object.  You can set the [content type](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ResponseObject#headers) of the response.  Also, you can use [tools.response_headers](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/BuiltinTools#tools.response_headers) to set the content type.

And, of course, there's an example of [File Download](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/FileDownload).

Comment: just correcting the link (typo)
from
http://https//developer.mozilla.org/en/Properly_Configuring_Server_MIME_Types
to
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Properly_Configuring_Server_MIME_Types